# Можно ли косвенную речь заключать в кавычки?

Tags: цитирование

На сайте https://russkiiyazyk.ru/leksika/tsitata.html пишется: "Цитата может вводиться в текст в виде косвенной речи с помощью подчинительного союза. Цитирование оформляется в виде придаточного предложения. Перед подчинительным союзом ставится запятая, а цитата заключается в кавычки и начинается со строчной буквы".

И далее приводится такой пример:

В. Г. Белинский считал, что «только труд может сделать человека счастливым, приводя его душу в ясность, гармонию и довольство самим собой».

Можно ли то, что заключено в кавычки в последнем предложении, назвать косвенной речью? Ведь по правилам, косвенная речь не заключается в кавычки.

А если все-таки заключено в кавычки, то можно ли это назвать отрывком из цитаты, если на этом же сайте приводится такое определение цитаты: "Цитата — это точное повторение высказывания с указанием автора или дословная выдержка отрывка текста".

Comment: Видимо, не в скобки, а в кавычки?

Answer (score 4):

```
 Можно ли косвенную речь заключать в кавычки?
```

А почему нет? Одно другому не мешает. Что такое косвенная речь? Косвенная речь – передача основного содержания чужой речи от лица автора, а не того, кто её произнёс, подумал, написал. Содержание чужой речи может быть подробное, без изменения (цитата), а может быть передано вкратце, сокращённо.

Способы введения цитат:

1. Как прямая речь (знаки препинания в предложениях с прямой речью).
2. Как косвенная речь:

N говорил (писал, считал, полагал), что «цитата».

3. При помощи вводных конструкций:

По словам (мнению) N, «цитата».

С точки зрения N, «цитата».

Так что цитата может быть передана и с помощью прямой речи, и с помощью косвенной речи.

Answer (score 2):

**Косвенная речь** — синтаксический способ введения в свою речь чужой речи **с сохранением основного содержания** высказывания, представленной как пояснительная придаточная часть **сложноподчинённого** предложения и находящейся в формальной зависимости от фразы передающего её лица. Присоединение к основной части предложения осуществляется с помощью различных союзов и соединительных слов (Википедия).

(1) В. Г. Белинский считал, что «только труд может сделать человека счастливым, приводя его душу в ясность, гармонию и довольство самим собой».

(2) В. Г. Белинский считал, что только труд может сделать человека счастливым,  дать ему ощущение ясности и гармонии.

В  обоих примерах мы пересказываем мысль Белинского, используя СПП с придаточным изъяснительным **(косвенную речь)**, но в первом случаю мы делаем это **дословно**, используя цитату, заключенную в кавычки. Во втором же случае это только **пересказ** содержания, поэтому кавычек нет, вот и нет цитирования.